# Where can I see a list of all renamed functions?

Tags: postgis

I'm clearing a large project of all legacy PostGIS code, and I'm looking for a comprehensive list of everything that *could* be a deprecated function call. I'm not going to change it all in one swoop -- I'm aware that POINT() is probably in some WKT and should not be replaced with ST_POINT(). But I'd still like to know them.

All the pages I've found so far just say "Stop using the deprecated functions!" and lists the new ones but I don't know for sure what every single one of the old ones is. It's not as simple as "All new ones without the prefix" because, for instance, I doubt there could have been a PostGIS COUNT() that was improved to ST_COUNT().

Answer (score 1):

There's no exact list that you are looking for, but most of the information you seek are in the comments of the SQL generation scripts:

- [postgis.sql.in](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/svn-trunk/postgis/postgis.sql.in) - most PostGIS functions, with a few deprecated signatures
- [legacy.sql.in](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/svn-trunk/postgis/legacy.sql.in) and [legacy_minimal.sql.in](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/svn-trunk/postgis/legacy_minimal.sql.in) - deprecated PostGIS functions from older versions

Also, take a look at the [documentation / tools for a *hard upgrade*](https://postgis.net/docs/postgis_installation.html#hard_upgrade) between versions. This handles upgrading of deprecated functions.

Comment: Thank you. Also, on the GitHub page for it, this looks like the closest to what I had in mind: https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/d1e5a63aac0078b6699702d8758dc1f0c7714841/doc/rfc/postgis_rfc_03_sheet.txt