# Undocumented PostGIS functions?

Tags: postgis

I'm migrating storage from ST_Geometry to PostGIS geometry and modifying some related SQL and Python. I noticed that the function `ST_PolyFromWKB` doesn't appear in the [latest PostGIS documentation](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-3.3/reference.html), but does appear in both the database itself and in [older PostGIS documentation](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.3/ch06.html). The function still appears to work normally and I'm fairly certain my database isn't referencing the identically-named function in the ST_Geometry library.

I would like to continue using this particular function since the syntax works for both PostGIS geometry and ST_Geometry, but am wary of continuing to rely on something that appears to be deprecated and could (soon?) go away. Is there PostGIS resource (e.g. in the documentation or in the library itself) indicating whether this function has been deprecated and/or when it will be removed? The answer for [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/319638/where-can-i-see-a-list-of-all-renamed-functions) gets me a little closer to what I want, but doesn't provide specific dates or a plan for deprecation/removal.

Comment: Welcome to GIS Stack Exchange. Your question is related to PostGIS features not addressing any specific postgis coding or database related problems. Kindly take the [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a detailed guideline of using this site.

Comment: I attempted to make the question more specific. Please let me know if this is more suitable for the GIS SE guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ST_[some_geometry_type]FromWKB` functions are comumented only for PostGIS 1.x. They do not appear in PostGIS 2.0 documentation https://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/reference.html#Geometry_Constructors.

Maybe because of this note:

> The functions given below are the ones which a user of PostGIS is
> likely to need. There are other functions which are required support
> functions to the PostGIS objects which are not of use to a general
> user.

Maybe the authors of the documentations were thinking that the ST_PolyFromWKB and others are needed only for ISO compatibility, and users could as well use the generic ST_GeomFromWKB for all their usual needs.

Comment: It's effectively just a wrapper around ST_GeomFromWKB with a 'polygon' type constraint: https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/b2df8046681ac9e644e278b63a59259f8763193b/postgis/postgis.sql.in#L5860

Comment: @user30184 Do you have a source for the ISO standards? I'm looking for a definitive answer about why ST_PolyFromWKB exists and what its fate is ... but I'm feeling less certain I'll get a definitive answer.

Comment: @robin loche I noticed that in GitHub as well, but I'm still left wondering 1) why it was ever included, 2) why it was apparently deprecated, and 3) if it will continue to be included in future PostGIS releases. I suspect the answer is likely relevant for many undocumented/deprecated functions besides ST_PolyFromWKB.

Comment: 1) It exists in other tools like ArcGIS so maybe that's why, and also they made wrapper for a lot of types and a lot of functions so maybe that's why they didn't made the doc for everything (maybe they changed the documentation between 1 and 2 and didn't rewrite all the doc ?) 2) I'm not sure if it is deprecated, the deprecated function seems to be marked like this in the commentary above it and that's not the case here 3) I would guess yes, and if not it's really just 2 lines, as long as there is ST_GeomFromWKB you can copy this function manually if needed

Comment: Maybe you can ask a ticket here, and ask for more info or at least mention the missing documentation: https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/report/1

Comment: Accepted this answer not because it exactly answered my question but because it got me closest to a solution. ST_PolyFromWKB does not appear to be deprecated, but I cannot determine if/when it will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

The OGC standard "OpenGIS Simple Features Specification For SQL Revision 1.1" https://portal.ogc.org/files/?artifact_id=829 defines the constrained functions in chapter "3.2.7.2 Language Constructs"

> The GeomFromWKB function, takes a well-known binary representation of
> geometry (WKBGeometry as described in section 3.3) and a Spatial
> Reference System ID (SRID) and creates an instance of the appropriate
> geometry type. This function plays the role of the Geometry Factory in
> SQL. An implementation shall substitute an SQL type used to represent
> binary values for the type Binary in the definitions below.
>
> ...
>
> return type of the Geometry function is the Geometry supertype. For
> construction of Geometry values to be stored in columns restricted to
> a particular subtype, an implementation shall also provide a type
> specific construction function for each instantiable subtype as
> described in the table below...

That version of the Simple Feature standard is now deprecated and I could not find a similar list from later version. However, PolyFromWKB does appear in one example even in version 1.2.1 of the standard https://portal.ogc.org/files/?artifact_id=25354.
Otherwise the standard states the following:

> 7.2.7 SQL routines for obtaining Well-known Binary Representations of a geometric object
>
> The SQL routines ST_AsBinary for obtaining the Well-known Binary
> Representation of a geometric object are specified in SQL/MM.

I guess that also the reversed functions are defined there but unfortunately ISO standards are not free and I do not have access to SQL/MM.

Probably the PostGIS functions have been implemented for the first version of the Simple Feature standard.